# When will NAnt reach version 1.0

Tags: nant

I like Nant very much. I do a lot of scripting with NAnt. It is a great little tool.

Since NAnt is pre 1.0, when problems occur, I often think if that it is a problem with NAnt itself, but this is not always the case.

One funny example: After running the oracle scripts I parsed the log output to make sure there was no problem. I was testing this with a small log file and it was fine.

I used the  task to load the file contents to a string property and used a regex to search for errors.

When I used this script for a large log file, I stopped getting the "build failed" message at the bottom, because I was printing the error messages.

Because the "build failed" was hiding at the top, I thought NAnt crashed, but it worked fine.

It would be better for NAnt to have a 1.0 release. Any reasons why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NAnt is an open source project that has been around a long while and is quite stable. While they have their reasons for not calling it version "1", does the version number really matter that much in this case? It's just a label.

I'd contact the team and find out what needs to be done before they label it as such and perhaps you can contribute some bug fixes etc...

The nice thing about the source being open is if you find a bug, you can fix it yourself. Hence the risk of it not being 1.0 is mitigated slightly if you're willing to invest a bit of time.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it matters... See the official blog - NAnt’s not dead, it was just resting

https://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/nant/2010/04/05/nants-not-dead-it-was-just-resting/

Comment: This URL has meanwhile become unreachable (probably as a part of SourceForge's hosted apps retirement).

Comment: (web archive)
https://web.archive.org/web/20100522194307/http://sourceforge.net/apps/wordpress/nant/2010/04/05/nants-not-dead-it-was-just-resting/

Answer (score 1):

Open Source projects tend to use more "modest" versions than commercial products which tend to be more marketing driven. A good example of the difference is the Java versioning scheme which went from 1.0 to 1.4 and then by the time it got to version 1.5 it flipped to using version 5 (though 1.5 is the internal name).